# I can't add an answer to indicate that I'm having the same problem as a previous poster

Tags: support, answers

I can't seem to add an "answer" to indicate I'm having the same problem as a previous poster; e.g.:

to question---> [External USB drive keeps unmounting and remounting using different UUID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214447/external-usb-drive-keeps-unmounting-and-remounting-using-different-uuid)

I tried to post---> ME-2:  Drive Label: 64GBFLASH...64GBFLASH1...64GBFLASH2...etc...

I've never posted an "answer" to previous posts, BUT the site tells me that I'm not allowed to post due to previous "bad answers"?

All of this leaves me to ask: how do existing problems get "escalated" by other victims for faster fixes?

Also, I'm not a "super-user" of Linux...just an average schmuck, so please don't curse me for asking.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: In general, it is better, that you **ask an own question instead of answering 'me too'** at an already existing question. Often problems are not the same even if you think so, but if they are, there are many people around here, who will link your question to an old question with an answer, that is probably a solution to your problem. If not, please keep asking for new ideas and more help. It is also important that you answer if helpers ask for something. They need that information in order to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Comment: It seems you have posted three "me too" answers and all of them were deleted, and that is why the system is blocking you from answering now. See [this page of the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: If you have a similar problem it is better to ask a question listing the problem, your computer specs and maybe link or list a similar question and say why it did not help.  I find google search will give a list of questions and maybe answers that might help, and doing can help yourself and maybe the poster of the question.

Comment: How does knowing that 2 (or 3 or 17) people have "thesa

Answer (score 10):

You should **not** post an answer because you have to same problem, unless you have some research which at least partially solves the problem. See the Help Center answer [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer):

> #### Have the same problem?
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on. You can also vote up the question or set a bounty on it so the question gets more attention.

Having the same problem with a slightly different configuration and posting your details generally speaking doesn't help solving the problem, and those answers are often flagged and/or commented on from the review queues:

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.